# Show a certain analytic function must exist

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $D - \{0\}$, where $D$ is the open unit disk. Suppose that $f$ has a pole of order one at $0$, with a residue equal to $n$ for some positive integer $n$. Show there is an analytic function $g$ such that $f = g'/g$ and such that $g$ has a zero of order $n$ at $0$.

Thoughts so far: I can see why $g$ would have a zero of order $n$ at $0$ (this follows from the argument principle), but I'm not sure how to show that such a $g$ exists. A hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We have $f(z) = n/z + h(z)$ in $D\setminus \{0\},$ with $h$ analytic in $D.$ We want this equal to $(z^na(z))'/z^na(z)$ for some $a$ analytic and nonzero in $D.$ See where this leads you.

Comment: I messed around with the equations and found that things would work out if $h(z) = a'(z)/a(z)$, and this is satisfied when $a = e^{q(z)}$, where $q$ is an antiderivative of $h$ (which we know exists locally since $h$ is holomorphic at $0$). Does this make sense?

Comment: Looks good $\ \ $